# Updating nested JSON sub-arrays by various keys

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2016 version, I can't tell if this is something specific to this version or whether I am missing something. I am trying to update a common property, `node_status`, inside an array of objects. The SQL update I am running to update `node_status` where `is_node_complete: false` is only updating the first index it finds rather than all that fit the query for `node_status`.

The JSON structure inside column `json_doc` in some_table

```
{
  "personnel": [
    {
      "node_id": "FDA64E9F-3BAC-45FA-8819-8A086D96B359",
      "node_data": {
        "is_approved": null,
        "is_node_complete": false,
        "node_status": "requested"
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "AF829232-32F4-464B-8817-50ED24447AA4",
      "node_data": {
        "is_approved": null,
        "is_node_complete": false,
        "node_status": "requested"
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "E18F8197-B16D-4E0B-8EE9-DBF5B23A8EB5",
      "node_data": {
        "is_approved": true,
        "is_node_complete": true,
        "node_status": "complete"
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "286700AE-81C8-4F4F-955D-D8DCE44ED30C",
      "node_data": {
        "is_approved": false,
        "is_node_complete": true,
        "node_status": "complete"
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "BC7BD024-70F1-459B-BDBF-945A3EED666C",
      "node_data": {
        "is_approved": null,
        "is_node_complete": false,
        "node_status": "requested"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My query to update column

```
DECLARE @rec_id INT = 1;;

WITH personnel_CTE
AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM some_table AS acm
    CROSS APPLY openjson(json_doc) WITH (personnel_node NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.personnel' AS json)
    CROSS APPLY openjson(personnel_node) pn
    WHERE id = @rec_id
        AND cast(json_value(pn.value, '$.node_data.is_node_complete') AS BIT) = 0
    )
UPDATE personnel_CTE
SET json_doc = json_modify(json_doc, '$.personnel[' + personnel_CTE.[key] + '].node_data.node_status', 'reviewer_assigned')
```

The guids are unique as well as the id for `some_table`. This is a truncated toy example, but these properties are the key items for the update.

Comment: Are you sure about the SQL Server version - with this version you can not use a variable or expression for `path` (second argument in the `JSON_MODIFY` call)?

Comment: I am aware of the string literal issue with 2016. I am using the Linux version of SQL server in my dev environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can update the JSON content with this statement (updating one row with values from multiple rows), but you may try with the following approach, which parses the JSON data as a table using `OPENJSON()`, updates this table and outputs the table's content as JSON using `FOR JSON PATH`:

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'
{
  "personnel": [
    {
      "node_id": "FDA64E9F-3BAC-45FA-8819-8A086D96B359",
      "node_data": {
        "is_approved": null,
        "is_node_complete": false,
        "node_status": "requested"
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "AF829232-32F4-464B-8817-50ED24447AA4",
      "node_data": {
        "is_approved": null,
        "is_node_complete": false,
        "node_status": "requested"
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "E18F8197-B16D-4E0B-8EE9-DBF5B23A8EB5",
      "node_data": {
        "is_approved": true,
        "is_node_complete": true,
        "node_status": "complete"
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "286700AE-81C8-4F4F-955D-D8DCE44ED30C",
      "node_data": {
        "is_approved": false,
        "is_node_complete": true,
        "node_status": "complete"
      }
    },
    {
      "node_id": "BC7BD024-70F1-459B-BDBF-945A3EED666C",
      "node_data": {
        "is_approved": null,
        "is_node_complete": false,
        "node_status": "requested"
      }
    }
  ]
}'
```

Table and statement:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (id int, json_doc nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTO some_table (id, json_doc) VALUES (1, @json)
INSERT INTO some_table (id, json_doc) VALUES (2, @json)

DECLARE @rec_id INT = 1;
UPDATE some_table
SET json_doc = (
    SELECT 
       node_id AS 'node_id',
       is_approved AS 'node_data.is_approved',
       is_node_complete AS 'node_data.is_node_complete',
       CASE 
          WHEN CONVERT(bit, is_node_complete) = 0 THEN 'reviewer_assigned'
          ELSE node_status 
       END AS 'node_data.node_status' 
    FROM OPENJSON (json_doc, '$.personnel') WITH (
       node_id nvarchar(36) '$.node_id',
       is_approved bit '$.node_data.is_approved',
       is_node_complete bit '$.node_data.is_node_complete',
       node_status nvarchar(50) '$.node_data.node_status'
    )
    FOR JSON PATH, ROOT ('personnel'), INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
)
WHERE id = @rec_id
```

Comment: This answer went in a different way than I expected. Tested it out and works great. Thank you!